# pdfquery not returning values in BBOX

Tags: python, pdf, pyquery

I am attempting to return the text within a desired bbox of a pdf using pdfquery library.

```
import pdfquery

pdf = pdfquery.PDFQuery("C:/Users/tyler.cowan/Desktop/PDF Miner/test.pdf")

test =  pdf.extract([
      ('UWI/API', 'LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("35.28,700.56,127.44,717.84")'),
 ])

print(test)
```

I first defined the bbox from the top left corner of the page this returned

```
{'UWI/API': [<LTTextLineHorizontal>, <LTTextLineHorizontal>, <LTTextLineHorizontal>, <LTTextLineHorizontal>, <LTTextLineHorizontal>, <LTTextLineHorizontal>, <LTTextLineHorizontal>, <LTTextLineHorizontal>]}
```

I then went on to define the bbox from the bottom left of the page and returned similar. I then went on to define a bbox that encompasses the entire page 8.5" x 11" and returned even more of the   values instead of all the text. Have I done something wrong here I was following along with the [Documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfquery#usage) under "Quick Start". I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

It said this just a bit further down that page under Bulk Data Scraping:

> (It’s often helpful to start with *('with_formatter', 'text')* so you get results like “Michaels” instead of [<'LTTextLineHorizontal>]. See Special Keywords below for more.)